# Managing Data-Role Tab on Blackberry 10 Webworks

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, blackberry-webworks

i have some problem. I made an application and i want to place the menu on tab manager blackberry.

Here's the code

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="actionbar">
        <div data-role="tab" data-overflow="true">
            <img src="images/ic_home.png" alt="action_home" />
            <p>Home</p>
            <img src="images/ic_notification.png" alt="action_notification" />
            <p>Notification</p>
        </div>
```

But it shows error  page the tabs is not working, like the picture below[image: error icons and div layout on blackberry webworks]

what i want is there are two lines of icon with description  then

I am using Jquerymobile as based on development.

how to fix this?

thanks in advance.

**UPDATE: it's working now,**

i miss conception for creating each data-role for each images. But still have problem, when i tested the design, it shows error.

like this: [image: error after selected tab is pressed]

please how to solve this? thanks

Comment: If it's working you should post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i miss interpret the docs

i can make it right by creating different divs

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<div data-role="actionbar">
    <div data-role="tab" data-overflow="true">
        <img src="images/ic_home.png" alt="action_home" />
        <p>Home</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="tab" data-overflow="true">
        <img src="images/ic_notification.png" alt="action_notification" />
        <p>Notification</p>
    </div>
```

and so on...